# (C program) Random Number Array program, and sort in ascending order, then find the median

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, median

I've created an array with random numbers, and then afterwards it will sort the numbers in ascending order, and then I want to print what the median is of the sorted numbers, but I have no idea what I'm doing wrong in my program, it just won't give me the median. I know it must be something that is so simple but I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong

```
int main() 
{

int *tenarray = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * SIZE);
int i;
int j;
int num;
int swap;
int median;
srand(time(NULL));

for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    num = rand() % 100;
    tenarray[i] = num;
    printf("%d\n", tenarray[i]);
}

for (i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
    for (j=0; j<SIZE+1; j++)
    {
        if(tenarray[j] > tenarray[j+1])
        {
            swap = tenarray[j];
            tenarray[j] = tenarray[j+1];
            tenarray[j+1] = swap;

        }
    }
}


for(i=0; i<SIZE; i++)
{
    printf("Ascending bubble sort is: %d\n", tenarray[i]);

}

median = (tenarray[5]);
printf("median is: %d\n", median);

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that they are in sorted order?  Have you done any kind of debugging yet?  If you had, you would probably find that you have written your sorting function incorrectly.  But I'll leave that as an exercise for you to figure out.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you always assume the median is "tenarray[5]"? This will only work if SIZE=11, you should do something like this:

```
if(SIZE%2==1)
    median = tenarray[SIZE/2];
else
    median = (tenarray[SIZE/2] + tenarray[(SIZE/2)-1])/2;
```